# AirPlane ToggleButton?

Tags: android, eclipse, mode, togglebutton, airplane-mode

I am trying to use a ToggleButton to switch AirPlane mode on and off. I am not sure how to go about this.

My permissions are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
```

My .XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
<ToggleButton  
android:id="@+id/Toggle" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textOn="On"
android:textOff="Off">
</ToggleButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Java has this for the toggle button:

```
AirToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.Toggle);
    AirToggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

        if (((ToggleButton)v).isChecked()){
            boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
            if(isEnabled == false)
            {
            Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,1);                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
            intent.putExtra("state", 1);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }

            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE");

            BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                  @Override
                  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        Log.d("AirplaneMode", "Service state changed");
                  }
            };

            context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);


            }

    };
});
```

}

UPDATE:
This is my log cat errors if that helps.

```
04-19 18:43:24.264: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233): ERROR: thread attach failed

04-19 18:43:25.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241): ERROR: thread attach failed

04-19 18:43:31.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due         to uncaught exception

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248): java.lang.NullPointerException

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at      com.simple.armor.SimpleArmor$1.onClick(SimpleArmor.java:30)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:98)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

04-19 18:43:31.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(248):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

04-19 18:43:31.573: ERROR/dalvikvm(248): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Please help.

-Thanks.

Comment: Which line is line 30? You have a null ref exception according to the logs. Did you read the logs? Also, you have two completely different statements on 1 line, on the line starting with "Settings.System.". That hurts baby kittens.

Comment: @Stealth Rabbi line thirty would be             boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
   And I honestly don't really know how to read the logs... I don't see were it says about line 30

Comment: @Christian, are you sure? You have two statements on that line. How can you tell which one the log is referring to? Move it to a seperate line regardless! The logs that you have provided are telling you there is a null reference exception as a result of executing the statement on line 30.

Comment: Where is context assigned? It's not shown in the code you've provided.

Comment: @Stealth Rabbi context is at the top as as "private Context context;. If I move the one statement to the next line the log cat will the tell me witch one is actually having the error?

Comment: Ok, so that's where you declare context, but where is it being *Assigned*?  I am assuming you are not doing this? If you are using (dereferencing) a pointer that is never assigned, you get a Null Reference Exception. You'd want to do something like context = getApplicationContext(), assuming this class derives from Activity.  As for the seperate line, yes. You can't really be sure what statement it's refeerring to if you have two statements one one line. What is your rationale for having these two statements on one line?

Comment: Okay, I added the context=getApplicationContext() and now it works great Thank you for the help on that. I just put the statement on the same line cause I didn't think it really mattered, but then again I never really used the log cat. I will learn to use the log cat better. Much thanks for your time and help it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: answer is accepted,but for others help
here is the tutorial post on how to [Control AirPlane Mode (ON/OFF)](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/09/control-airplane-mode-onoff-android.html) you can refer this link for detailed info about how to acheive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments attached to question. The variable 'context' was not assigned, resulting in a Null Reference Exception. There isn't anything wrong with the logic behind setting the Air Plane mode setting.