# Turn off airplane mode [A continued question]

Tags: android, eclipse, togglebutton

Okay so now I can turn on the airplane mode (thanks to the help of Stealth Rabbi in my other post. [AirPlane ToggleButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718844/airplane-togglebutton/5724864#5724864)). The problem now is when I click my toggle button to turn Airplane mode off nothing happens, exept for the toggle button switches from on to off but does not change  the state of airplane mode.
Any suggestions are appretiated.

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. 
'

```
public void onClick(View v){
            context = getApplicationContext();
        if (((ToggleButton)v).isChecked()){
            boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
            if(isEnabled == false)
            {
            Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,1);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
            intent.putExtra("state", 1);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }



            }else
            {

                Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,0);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
                intent.putExtra("state", 0);
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);

            }

    };
});`
```

In the else part of the code I changed the number one to number 0.

Answer (score 1):

You have to broadcast the [ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED) to notify the system that you changed the settings